# How to uninstall Chrome OS and install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, chromebook, chromeos

I recently bought a Lenovo s345 Chromebook without investigating what a Chromebook is. I thought that I could just install Ubuntu in a normal way like I always do, but I hit a wall.

How to uninstall Chrome OS completely and install Ubuntu as the main and only distro?

Is it possible to make Chromebook run live USB distros like Kali Linux/Tails?

Comment: You can install Ubuntu on a Chromebook. There's a tutorial here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#1-overview

Comment: That's the thing, i don't want to preserve the ChromeOS because i have issues with google and privacy. Shouldn't have bought the Chromebook in the first place, stupid of me....

Answer (score 0):

Well i researched for a few hours and i decided to sell it, gonna lose some money but i don't want this headache of a pc, if you can even call it a pc with google running on it. My mistake... gonna buy a normal pc with BIOS...

Comment: I would personally recommend the Dell New XPS 13/15/17. If you are buying a new laptop.